# animation duration in css

Tags: css, css-animations

Animation-duration is used to determine how long the animation plays, but whether this animation-duration represents each frame or the entire frame, for example :

animation-duration: 10s

Does this mean that each frame is played for 10s or that the entire frame is played for 10s

Comment: There is no "frame" in animations, what are you referring to?  Also   You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: there's no frames, the browser will run at whatever fps is feasible. `animation-duration` describes the time it takes for the animation to play from 0% to 100%. The browser determines what to show for each frame. [try it out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration).